# unicorn RuntimeError because of dalli

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, dalli

Unicorn is in a loop and showing the error below:

unicorn error

> ERROR -- : Could not find cache store adapter for dalli_store (cannot
>   load such file -- active_support/cache/dalli_store) (RuntimeError)

production.rb

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, "127.0.0.1:11211", { :namespace => "my-app", :expires_in => 3600 }
```

gemfile

```
gem 'dalli', '~>2.1.0', :git => "git://github.com/mperham/dalli.git"
```

I tested in rails console and seems like no problem with dalli.

```
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.8)
irb(main):001:0> Rails.cache.write("hello", "world")
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Rails.cache.read("hello")
=> "world"

irb(main):002:0> Rails.cache
=> #<ActiveSupport::Cache::DalliStore:0xabaefc8 @options={:namespace=>"my-app", :expires_in=>3600, :compress=>nil}, @raise_errors=false, @data=#<Dalli::Client:0xabaef00 @servers=["127.0.0.1:11211"], @options={:namespace=>"my-app", :expires_in=>3600, :compress=>nil}, @ring=#<Dalli::Ring:0xa2db0e0 @servers=[#<Dalli::Server:0xa2db158 @hostname="127.0.0.1", @port=11211, @weight=1, @fail_count=0, @down_at=nil, @last_down_at=nil, @options={:down_retry_delay=>1, :socket_timeout=>0.5, :socket_max_failures=>2, :socket_failure_delay=>0.01, :value_max_bytes=>1048576, :username=>nil, :password=>nil, :keepalive=>true, :namespace=>"my-app", :expires_in=>3600, :compress=>nil}, @sock=#<Dalli::Server::KSocket:fd 8>, @msg=nil, @pid=27069, @inprogress=false, @lock=#<Monitor:0xa2db0a4 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0xa2db07c>>, @version="1.4.2", @error=nil>], @continuum=nil, @failover=true>>>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. How can i manually restart unicorn?

Comment: What do you mean by manually restart unicorn?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone runs into similar problem:
I've removed Gemfile.lock and dalli gemspec file downloaded by bundler (somewhere like /path/to/app/shared/bundler/gems/ruby/1.8/specifications/dalli.gemspec), ran 'bundle install' and it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and in my case it was caused by **'rvm'**

(My setup is Phushion-Passenger, Rails3, Memcached )

I fixed it with:

```
rvm all do gem install uuidtools
```

,

```
rvm all do gem install dalli
```

,

```
rvm all do gem install kgio
```

,

```
rvm all do gem bundle install
```

and now my memcached stats show:

```
# nc 127.0.0.1 11211

stats

STAT pid 23112
STAT uptime 53446
STAT time 1367778065
STAT version 1.4.5
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 0.692043
STAT rusage_system 0.000000
STAT curr_connections 7
STAT total_connections 11
STAT connection_structures 8
STAT cmd_get 19
STAT cmd_set 10
STAT cmd_flush 0
STAT get_hits 5
STAT get_misses 14
STAT delete_misses 0
STAT delete_hits 0
STAT incr_misses 0
STAT incr_hits 0
STAT decr_misses 0
STAT decr_hits 0
STAT cas_misses 0
STAT cas_hits 0
STAT cas_badval 0
STAT auth_cmds 0
STAT auth_errors 0
STAT bytes_read 2326
STAT bytes_written 8910
STAT limit_maxbytes 67108864
STAT accepting_conns 1
STAT listen_disabled_num 0
STAT threads 4
STAT conn_yields 0
STAT bytes 1377
STAT curr_items 10
STAT total_items 10
STAT evictions 0
STAT reclaimed 0
END
```

Hope this helps